# BaseX attributes cannot be serialized

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery, basex

I have this simple XML file:

```
<catalog>
  <product dept="WMN">
    <number>557</number>
    <name language="en">Fleece Pullover</name>
    <colorChoices>navy black</colorChoices>
  </product>
  <product dept="ACC">
    <number>563</number>
    <name language="en">Floppy Sun Hat</name>
  </product>
  <product dept="ACC">
    <number>443</number>
    <name language="en">Deluxe Travel Bag</name>
  </product>
  <product dept="MEN">
    <number>784</number>
    <name language="en">Cotton Dress Shirt</name>
    <colorChoices>white gray</colorChoices>
    <desc>Our<i>favorite</i>shirt!</desc>
  </product>
</catalog>
```

I am reading a book called [XQuery by Priscila Walmsley](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596006349) and it says to type the command:

```
doc("catalog.xml")/*/product/@dept
```

so I type in BaseX

```
xquery doc("catalog.xml")/*/product/@dept
```

and I am getting this error:

```
Error:
[SENR0001] Attributes cannot be serialized:attribute dept { "WMN" }.
```

Despite that the book that says:

> will return the four dept attributes in the input document.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This may just be a limitation of your test environment. For example, try forcing it to serialize as a string: `xquery doc("catalog.xml")/*/product/@dept/string()`

Comment: great @wst good catch! If you care to put it in an answer it will be good for other users `xquery doc("catalog.xml")/*/product/string(@dept)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

BaseX is just being strict about serialization. It won't complain if you force the attribute nodes into strings:

```
xquery doc("catalog.xml")/*/product/@dept/string()
```

Comment: actually this has been tested and worked: `xquery doc("catalog.xml")/*/product/string(@dept)`

Answer (score 2):

The [XQuery 3.1 Serialization](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-xquery-serialization-31/#adaptive-output) specification provides the new "adaptive" serialization mode, which allows the serialization of attribute and namespace nodes. Since Version 8.0 of BaseX, this mode is used as new default.