# Error when get attributes with xquery in basex 7.9

Tags: xpath, xquery, basex

This is the XML input:

```
<bookstore>
  <book category="COOKING">
  <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>  
  <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
    <year>2005</year>
   <price>30.00</price>
  </book>
  <book category="CHILDREN">
    <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
    <author>J K. Rowling</author>
    <year>2005</year>
    <price>29.99</price>
  </book>
</bookstore>
```

I am using BaseX 7.9. When I request attributes,

```
for $book in collection()/bookstore/book
return $book/@*
```

an error occurs:

`[SENR0001] Attributes cannot be serialized: attribute category {"COOKING"}.`

How can this be fixed? Thanks for helping me!

Comment: Well, we honestly can't tell you more than the error message already does: Attributes can not be serialized. This is what your query is doing. If you want to get the attribute values, you could for example use `@*/data()`. If you need more help, you have to specify what you want to get back as result

Comment: thanks dirkk 
i want to get exactly attribute @category.
it is xsi:type attribute.

i use @*/string() then get back result is "COOKING CHILDREN", it is a string. I do not want it

Comment: Cooking children sounds delicious, why don't you want it?

Comment: Kidding aside, you do get the result back for attribute category. It simply is a concatenation of both results (you iterate over both books and you get back the attributes of each of them). So, what do you want to get back? What is the expected result?

Comment: i use Basex 6.7.1 then get attributes by @* is well. Why basex 7.9 is not working.

Comment: :)) 
i want to use function.
declare function local:getAttribute($attributes as attribute()*) as attribute()*
{{    
    for $attribute in $attributes
    where matches($attribute,"(^|\W)COOKING(\W|$)","i") and name($attribute) != "xsi:type" and name($attribute) != 'id'
    return $attribute   
}};

then,  return local:getAttribute($book/@*)

Comment: It is not "not working" in BaseX 7.9, it is defined behaviour. BaseX is just strict about serialization. As I said before, use `data()` (or `string()`) to return the attribute value, which is what you are most likely interested in.

Comment: possible duplicate of [BaseX attributes cannot be serialized](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24663393/basex-attributes-cannot-be-serialized)

Answer (score 1):

The [XQuery 3.1 Serialization](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-xquery-serialization-31/#adaptive-output) specification provides the new "adaptive" serialization mode, which allows the serialization of attribute and namespace nodes. Since Version 8.0 of BaseX, this mode is used as new default.

This was different in earlier versions of the specification, which did not allow attributes to be output on their own (see the error code `SENR0001` for more information).

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24663393/basex-attributes-cannot-be-serialized